# Print messages' guild name

Tags: node.js, bots, discord, discord.js

I need to print the name of the guild messages are sent in, like this:

```
command.log(msg.guild.name)
```

I need to know what var I should use, I don’t want the Id of the guild.

Comment: have you checked the api/docs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I will assume that you need them to be printed in the `console`.

As the docs say, there's a [`name`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Guild?scrollTo=name) property in `Guild`. You can get the guild of a `Message` by the property of the same name: note that if it was a private message the guild will be `undefined`.
Here's a sample implementation:

```js
client.on('message', msg => {
  let {guild} = msg;
  console.log(guild ? `New message in ${guild.name}` : "New private message");
});
```

Comment: This does not work anymore with the new discord.js update.

Answer (score 0):

```
let guildname = guild.name
```

Not that hard, look at the docs first.

Answer (score 0):

Very easy, check the docs

```
client.on('message', msg => {
  let {guild} = msg;
  console.log(guild ? `New message in ${guild.name}` : "New private message");
});
```